# Value of type * has no member 'rx'

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive, rx-cocoa

I'm trying to make a small reactive wrapper for ImageDownloader from AlamofireImage:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit.UIImage
import AlamofireImage
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift


extension Reactive where Base: ImageDownloader {

    public func download(urlRequest: URLRequest, filter: ImageFilter?) -> Observable<UIImage> {

        return Observable.create { observer in

            self.base.download(urlRequest, filter: filter) { response in

                if let error = response.error {
                    observer.onError(error)
                } else if let image = response.value {
                    observer.onNext(image)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles without a problem. But when I try to call `rx.download` on an instance of ImageDownloader I get an error saying that there is no 'rx' extension there:

[image: Value of type 'ImageDownloader' has no member 'rx' error]

Any guesses why this is happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to conform to `ReactiveCompatible` protocol first and then you can use 'rx' in your downloadRequest call

```
import AlamofireImage
import RxSwift

extension ImageDownloader: ReactiveCompatible {}

extension Reactive where Base: ImageDownloader {

    public func download(urlRequest: URLRequest, filter: ImageFilter?) -> Observable<UIImage> {

        return Observable.create { observer in
            let requestReceipt = ImageDownloader.default.download(urlRequest, filter: filter) { response in
                if let error = response.error {
                    observer.onError(error)
                } else if let image = response.value {
                    observer.onNext(image)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create {
               requestReceipt?.request.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now you can call `ImageDownloader.default.rx.download(urlRequest:filter:)` method like below

```
let imageRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL(string: "https://imageserver.com/image/myimage.png")!)
let imageObservable: Observable<UIImage> = ImageDownloader.default.rx.download(urlRequest: imageRequest, filter: nil)
```

Comment: yeah, that's exactly it. Thanks!

Comment: Update: as of Xcode 11.3, Swift 5 the OP code does not even compile.

Comment: I pretty much always used types that already conform to that protocol, like `UIView`s. At first I was totally lost with that error, but now it all makes sense. :-)